# Correct / Best way of calling model methods inside view.html.php

Tags: joomla-3.4, view, model

Which is the correct/best method of calling model methods inside view.html.php.

**Method 1**

```
$mydata = $this->get('MyData') ;
```

**Method 2**

```
$model = $this->getModel() ;
$mydata = $model->getMyData() ;
```

I feel is the Method 2 is the best because I can even pass arguments to the model (if required).

Answer (score 2):

I think `$mydata = $this->get('MyData');` is the best way to call model's functions if you don't need to pass any argument.

Model's function are already available in the MVC view logic and using the second method to reload the model feels redundant to me. Usually I write my component's model functions using only arguments passed trough GET or POST and write other functions, that needs args, in the *Helper class*.

Comment: Calling getModel does actually reload the model it just returns a reference to the instance.