# Calling a Model's Method from View

Tags: joomla-3.x, component, mysql, mvc

I have a function in my model to sum several columns of a table.

```
public static function get_sums()
    {
        // Create a new query object.
        $db    = $this->getDbo();
        $query = $db->getQuery(true);

        // Select the required fields from the table.

        $query
            ->select('SUM'($db->quoteName(array('pb_p','pb_s','pb_t','pb_r', 'jc_p','jc_s','jc_t','jc_r','sc_p', 'sc_s','sc_t','sc_r','my_p','my_s','my_t','my_r'))));

        $db->loadResults();

    }
```

In my view.html file added

```
$model = $this->getModel( );
$this->get_sums= $model->get_sums();
```

But it throws an error

```
Using $this when not in object context
```

I am stumped trying to get this to work, can anyone offer advice where I am going wrong?
TIA
Steve

Comment: The issue here is on the top, literally.  `static` function can't have `$this->` in it.

Comment: @Alexandr - He has changed his question since then.

Comment: Steve - if you have a different question - just open up a new one. Don't overwrite and changing your previous question.

Comment: Thanks guys I just used a foreach loop to sum the columns it was easier than trying to figure out the query

Comment: @Alexandr and you are right about the static functions.

Answer (score 0):

The title of your question should be something like calling Model Methods from View - the "sum a query from database" is misleading as title.

By the way, for your actual problem and not for the title of the question: **[Correct / Best way of calling model methods inside view.html.php](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/14345/correct-best-way-of-calling-model-methods-inside-view-html-php)**.

Just to prepare you, when you manage to find your way to call your model's method from your view, you will encounter another error.

`$db->loadResults()` - As far as I know, there isn't a such method in **JDatabase class**.

I haven't read your query at all to know what you are doing in there and what kind of data you will expect, but the **JDatabase** on retrieving data from DB should help:

[**Selecting Data using JDatabase**](https://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase)

Comment: Thanks for the link, it should be load Result no s thanks

Comment: The issue here is not related to the question that marked as duplicate.

Comment: I don't see a `setQuery()` call before `loadResult()` either @FFr